# Angular pdf download in code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, download

I want to let users download a pdf, but because the route to download the pdf is secured (i have to send a jwt token), i can't simply use a href.

I have to following code that downloads the pdf first, and then creates a link tag or a blob depending on the browser. But when i try to download, i get a network error.

When i log the data from the response for the pdf, i get something like this: %PDF-1.4↵%����↵3 0 obj↵<>↵startxref↵6859040↵%%EOF↵".

Do i need to convert the pdf first before making a blob or create the link tag? Or am i doing this the wrong way?

Here's my code:
The first function downloads the pdf and the second one creates the blob or link tag so the browser downloads the file.

```
  public exportPDF(uuid:number):IPromise<string> {
    let config:IHttpProviderDefaults = {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'
        }
    };

    return this.$http.get(this.applicationParams.baseUrl + '/rapporten/' + uuid)
        .then((resp:IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<string>) => {
            return resp.data;
        }, (error:IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>) => {
            switch (error.status) {
                case 403:
                    toastr.error(error.data.errorCode);
                    break;
                case 404:
                    toastr.error(error.data.errorCode);
                    break;
                default:
                    toastr.error('Fout bij het exporteren van de pdf');
                    break;
            }
        });
}

public downloadFile(pdf:string, fileName:string):void {
    let filename:string = '' + fileName;

    if (this.$window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var blob:any = new Blob([pdf], {
            type: "application/octet-stream"
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else{

        var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
        anchor.css({display: 'none'}); // Make sure it's not visible
        angular.element(document.body).append(anchor); // Attach to document

        anchor.attr({
            href: 'application/octet-stream' + pdf,
            target: '_blank',
            download: 'test'
        })[0].click();
    }
}
```